# Not able to copy url with custom share icon in wordpress framework

Tags: wordpress, url, copy, share

[image]

all other social connectivity icons working with functioanlity, i am facing problem with "COPY" icon, when i click it goes to blank page, it should work the URL to copy

copy icon is not default action come with wordpress share addon, i am added customly

please help